# CSS inline-block issue

Tags: css

I've been working on a CSS layout for a webpage of a friend of mine and encountered a few problems. Maybe, you'll be able to help me with them.

First problem was the fact that my css did not seem to acknowledge "repeat-y" on my 1px bg file. It did when I hardcoded the "height" value, but it's not something I can do since the project is MVC3 and the content is generated dynamically. What I did is I ran javascript function "onload" that measured filled up div and set the correct height for the problematic "repeat-y" divs. The solution is not perfect as it loads the page without the "repeat-y"s, and loads them only upon load completion, so there is a visible change. Do you have any ideas on how to make it pure CSS?

The second problem a little bit more annoying is that when i finally started to display the "repeat-y"s the "inline-block" broke (I presume). Now it Looks like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1201937/CSS.png.
So the middle div is pushed down. The displacement is not constant. When I loaded a page with three times more content it actually got a lot smaller. But I doesn't change the fact that it's unacceptable.

Some code now:

HTML:

```
<div class="contentMid">
    <div id="leftHeight" class="contentML">
    </div>
    <div id="measuredDiv" class="contentM">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="rightHeight" class="contentMR">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contentMid 
{
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}

.contentMid .contentML
{
    background-image: url("/content/images/content-shadow-l.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width:30px;
}

.contentMid .contentMR
{
    background-image: url("/content/images/content-shadow-r.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    margin-left:2px;
    width:25px;    
}

.contentMid .contentM
{
    padding: 0px 10px 20px 10px;
    background-color:#f5f5f5; 
    margin-left:2px; 
    width:949px;
}
```

If it interests anybody this is the JS script.

```
function fixHeights(){
    document.getElementById("leftHeight").style.height = document.getElementById("measuredDiv").offsetHeight + "px";
    document.getElementById("rightHeight").style.height = document.getElementById("measuredDiv").offsetHeight + "px";
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

PS. Oh. The problem is cross-browser FF/IE/Ch

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/the_r/ZEw5M/. Notice what happens when you delete JS Script. The content is not displaced, but you don't get the shadows on left and right

Comment: Did you know the http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ page. There you can make crossbrowser compatible css grantient without background-image ? It might help you

Comment: it's not very clear what you need. a picture of what it should look like would help, a jsiddle example would help even more..

Comment: The white-ish panel should not be split, ant the shadows on the sides should not end halfway. Sorry. I thought it was obvoius. Here is a screenshot of what it Should look like: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1201937/CSS2.png

Comment: Ok. I've added JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/c2wLP/1/. Yes the side shadows are not transparent. And the naming convention if there is one is abysmal.

Comment: sorry. Wrong JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/the_r/ZEw5M/. Notice what happens when you delete JS Script. The Content is not displaced, but you don't get the shadows on left and right

Answer (score 0):

add this to the css:

```
.contentMid:after{
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: yea sorry i should have explained this is basically doing the same thing that: <div style="clear: both"></div> would do if put before the closing tag of <div class="contentMid"> just without the need of extra html. It clears all floats with invisible content.